# How to output the amount of comments left by a user with JComments / Joomla 3?

Tags: php, joomla, comments, joomla3.0

JoomlaTune - developers of the JComments extension - offers the following code to display comments anywhere:

```
    <?php
            $comments = JPATH_SITE . '/components/com_jcomments/jcomments.php';
                if (file_exists($comments)) {
                require_once($comments);
                $options = array();
                $options['object_id'] = $this->item->id;
                $options['object_group'] = 'com_content';
                $options['published'] = 1;
                $count = JCommentsModel::getCommentsCount($options);
                echo ('<span>'. $count .'</span>');
            }
    ?>
```

by substituting the id of the article into $this->item->id you can get the number of materials for this article.

Is it possible to somehow adapt this code to display the number of comments left by specific users by his id. Or maybe this variable already exists somewhere in the component code?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: I'm not really sure what I'm looking at, but a quick google search says there's a `JComments::showComments` function that you should be able to get all comments then loop through them to filter out comments from specific users?

Comment: Also you could dig through this https://github.com/ThomDietrich/jcomments I bet there's lots of good stuff to look at for potential additions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

all you need to do is add the following code:

```
use Joomla\CMS\Factory;
$user = Factory::getUser();
$options['userid'] = $user->id;
```

just before:

```
$count = JCommentsModel::getCommentsCount($options);
```